# Setting PostgreSql transaction lock with NpgSql

Tags: database, postgresql, locking, postgresql-9.3, npgsql

I have this app that does a few (between 2 and 10) concurrent select-only requests to PostgreSql 9.3 using NpgSql 2.2.0, and most of the time at least 2 of them timeout.

When I check the locks during execution, I can see that each request has an ACCESS SHARE lock, but is in a transaction which has EXCLUSIVE lock. I think the timeout is because all requests are fired approximately at the same time, and the latter ones cannot get the EXCLUSIVE lock in due time.

I've tried using explicit transactions and setting the isolation level to ReadUncommitted, but that doesn't change anything. Here's the pattern I use:

```
using (var con = new NpgsqlConnection(Configuration.B2bConnectionString))
{
    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(string.Format(@"SELECT shop_id, ean, brand, label1, label2, containing, image_url, cc.cat_key, cc.cat1, cc.cat2, cc.cat3, cc.cat_string     
        FROM b2b_data.cms_catalog_products_candidates cpc 
        JOIN b2b_data.cms_catalog_categories cc ON cc.cat_key = cpc.cat_key
        WHERE etat IN ('5','6','61') AND ean IN ({0})", string.Join(",", eans.Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x))))
    , con);

    con.Open();
    using (var t = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
    {
        using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //buid object, add it to list
            }
        }
        t.Commit();
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I used Wireshark to monitor what's sent to the DB. I can see the READ COMMITTED  isolation level for each transaction, but there isn't any occurence of "LOCK" in the payload of any of the packets sent to the server. Which leads me to think that this lock issue comes from the server itself rather than the Npgsql driver. For what it's worth, it's an Amazon RDS.

1. Is my assumption correct about the issue?
2. Would setting the transaction lock to access share resolve it?
3. How can I do that, if isolation level ReadUncommited is not evough?

Comment: SELECT statements only need ACCESS SHARE locks. An EXCLUSIVE lock allows concurrent ACCESS SHARE locks. PostgreSQL doesn't automatically acquire EXCLUSIVE locks. (ACCESS EXCLUSIVE, yes, but not EXCLUSIVE.) So it looks like either you or npgsql is acquiring the EXCLUSIVE lock. [Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/explicit-locking.html)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall': Yes I know it's not supposed to be exclusive, and that's what I'd like to change.

Comment: Also, when you ask for "read uncommitted", PostgreSQL gives you "read committed". [Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html)